# Is there anything wrong with my Django urls.py code?

Tags: python, django, backend

I have been developing a django app and the URL i want to go to says it's 404 Not Found
because there is a **space** in between the URL??? (see URL no. 10 below)
[image]

**Is there anything wrong with my code???**
urls.py in meditatetimer app:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import main, stop

urlpatterns = [
    path('', main),
    path('/stop', stop)
]
```

urls.py in project:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.urls.conf import include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('landing.urls')),
    path('roles/productivity/planner/', include('planner.urls')),
    path('roles/productivity/memo/', include('memo.urls')),
    path('roles/productivity/focus-timer/', include('focustimer.urls')),
    path('roles/meditation/meditate-timer/', include('meditatetimer.urls')),
    path('roles/meditation/diary/', include('diary.urls')),
    path('roles/meditation/qotd/', include('qotd.urls')),
]
```

views.py in meditatetimer app:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import TimeForm
from .models import Event

def main(request):
    time_form = TimeForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        #if time_form.is_valid():
        time_form.save()
        return redirect('/roles/meditation/meditate-timer')
    else:
        time_form = TimeForm()

    timer = Event.objects.all()
    context = {
        'timer': timer,
        'time_form' : time_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def stop(request):
    timer = Event.objects.all()
    timer.delete()
    return redirect ('/roles/meditation/meditate-timer')
```

if I remove the slash in meditatetimer's url would only show the same thing, but now it's
roles/meditation/meditate-timer/ stop (the space will still be there)

Thank you in advance, I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slash goes on the final of url not in the begin

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import main, stop

urlpatterns = [
    path('', main),
    path('stop/', stop)
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not start the path with a slash, since then there are two slashes: one of the upper URL:

```
path('roles/meditation/meditate-timer/', …)
                                      ↑
```

and one of the `/stop`:

```
path('/stop', …)
      ↑
```

You thus should remove the leading slash:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import main, stop

urlpatterns = [
    path('', main),
    #     ↓ no leading slash
    path('stop/', stop)
]
```